# Rocket framework portability to web based applications

Tags: c#, windows, forms, web-applications

I am designing a windows form application. I want also to provide a web based front for the same application. I understand that I need to redesign the UI part wholly and I am ready for that.

But what I would like to know is that what architecture should I follow during development of the windows form so that the maximum part can be reusable. By maximum part I mean the data access logic, the business logic etc.

I am planning to use Rocket Framework http://rocketframework.codeplex.com/ for windows application design. Are any one familiar with it? Please suggest.

Comment: People still write Windows Forms apps?!

Comment: ya..they do...may be they will discover the better(may be) tomorrow!..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of R&D and extensive study I finally settled here: https://github.com/geersch/ModelViewPresenter It is an MVP architecture written by Christophe Geers. It supports all I needed- Architecture for winform, web portability support, Entity Framework. Really nice and easy to use.

**Additional reading:**
http://www.cerquit.com/blogs/post/MVP-Part-I-e28093-Building-it-from-Scratch.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the linkback. My post is only meant to explore the MVP pattern. It supports a very simple Web and WinForms application. I'm sure you'll run into more complex use cases, but it's a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

[MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter) or [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) should enable use to re-use portions of your application.

Of Interest?: [Implementing MVC with Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654722/implementing-mvc-with-windows-forms)

Comment: Thnx Mitch..the 3rd link was really helpful to solve my problem.

Comment: I agree with Mitch, just use a MVP pattern. ie, no codebehind. Or very little.