# Start controller from Program.cs instead of form

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller

I want to build an application in C#, using the MVC pattern. I want first to create an instance of my controller and pass it a form as a parameter.

Here is the normal C# way (default):

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new mainForm(new Controller()));
}
```

The problem with this is that I don't want my mainForm class be able to access the Controller. I just want the controller to "see" the other objects.

I want something like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    Controller cnt = new Controller(new mainForm());
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(cnt);
}
```

This doesn't work though, because the method Run takes either a Form as an argument or an ApplicationContent. How can I do this?

Comment: Is it WPF ? Check out MVVM frameworks like Caliburn.Micro.

Comment: no, not really. I have the application already built, but it's not following the MVC pattern. I'm under time pressure, so... won't have time to learn new stuff atm, just want to find a solution to this, thanks though.

Comment: It's still not very clear if it's a WinForms or WPF application. I'm assuming WPF but I might be wrong.

Comment: It's a WinForms application.

Comment: Yeah so use an `ApplicationContext` that has a `MainForm`.

Comment: Why do you not want the main form to access the controller ? I'm not sure going "full mvc" with a "real" decoupling of objects would be easily done without either a heavy rewrite of your architecture, or using a preexisting framework. Check out this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654722/implementing-mvc-with-windows-forms

Comment: Deriving Controller from ApplicationContext is a simple and logical workaround.  After all, it should be the controller that decides when the app should terminate.  Do avoid reinventing this wheel, there are many MVC implementations around.