# Using custom data classes with Windows Forms

Tags: c++, .net, winforms, visual-c++

Ive been searching for an answer to this question for a while now but haven't seem to come across anything clear.

Suppose I have a custom data class `MyClass` that i want to use for back-end storage and computation of data that will be displayed in a form `MyForm`. What is the best way of instantiating `MyClass` so that the data inside of it will be accessible to `MyForm` during runtime? Is this even possible to do with a Windows Form, or is there an easier way of displaying information stored in a custom made *C++* class with a GUI?

Comment: Consider using Qt for C++ GUI development: http://www.qt.io/

Comment: Please see if this QA is useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654722/implementing-mvc-with-windows-forms

Comment: Winforms supports data binding.  Well covered in MSDN, you'll have to RTFM.

Comment: @HansPassant  I've tried using the official documentation, the problem is that the official documentation does not seem to be updated for Visual Studio 2015 regarding this issue. When following the general instructions listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xf878ky.aspx), it says to use the "Data Source Configuration Wizard". However, the instructions given to run the wizard don't seem to work in VS 2015 CE, as I'm not given the menu choices that it says I should be given. And searching through both the menus in VS as well as online have failed to produce any helpful results.

Comment: The various data related designers were never available for C++, only C# and VB.NET.  C++ programmers are supposed to know how to write code without help.  C# is a nice language, give it a try.

Comment: @HansPassant So in short what I'm trying to do is indeed not possible? Great. Thanks for filling me in though.