# which of the following is better for eventhandling

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, event-handling

Ok so I'm just making a mock MVC app to get a handle on how things work
my model has some string in it (and more, but don't care at the moment)
my GUI has a bunch of radiobuttons and here is what I do

```
private class radioButtonEvent : Model.EventHandling.XObjectEvent{
        private List<RadioButton> myList;
        public radioButtonEvent() { }
        public override void execute(){
            foreach (RadioButton a in myList){
                if (a.Text == ((Model.InfoTree)myObj).Info){
                    a.Checked = true;
                    ((TabControl)a.Parent.Parent).SelectTab(a.Parent.Name);
                }
            }
        }
        public void setRadioList(List<RadioButton> a){
            myList = a;
        }
    }
```

I create one of these and add a list of all my radiobuttons then make it listen to a certain string, like so:

```
        radioButtonEvent locationEvent = new radioButtonEvent();
        List<RadioButton> radioList = new List<RadioButton>();
        radioList.Add(Location_Logged_Arena_radioButton);
        radioList.Add(Location_Logged_Market_radioButton);
        radioList.Add(Location_Logged_Mute_radioButton);
        radioList.Add(Location_Logged_Town_radioButton);
        radioList.Add(Location_Logged_Vault_radioButton);
        radioList.Add(Location_Logging_Home_radioButton);
        radioList.Add(Location_Logging_Select_radioButton);
        locationEvent.setRadioList(radioList);
        myModel.InformationTree.addInfoEvent(locationEvent);
```

one thing I should point out is that in XObjectEvent there is a method that gets inherited that handles the setting of myobj

now the two ways I've currently thought of going about having listenable strings are these:
**Way 1:**

```
    private ListenableString lstring = new ListenableString();
    public string Info{
        get
        { return lstring.Text;}
        set
        { lstring.Text = value;}

    }
    public void addInfoEvent(XEvent ev){
        lstring.addEvent(ev);
    }
```

and this uses the following

```
class ListenableString
{
    public ListenableString() { }
    private string me = "";
    private List<XEvent> Events = new List<XEvent>();
    public void addEvent(XEvent ev){
        Events.Add(ev);
    }
    public string Text{
        get
        { return me;}
        set{
            me = value;
            foreach (EventHandling.XObjectEvent x in Events){
                x.setObject(this);
                x.execute();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Way 2:**

```
    private List<XEvent> infoEvents = new List<XEvent>();
    public void addInfoEvent(XEvent ev)
    {
        infoEvents.Add(ev);
    }
    private string _Info = "";
    public string Info
    {
        get
        {
            return _Info;
        }
        set
        {
            _Info = value;
            foreach (EventHandling.XObjectEvent x in infoEvents)
            {
                x.setObject(this);
                x.execute();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Way 3**
got a better way? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ye Olde New Answer**

Here are some Stack Overflow questions that deal with implementing MVC in a Windows Form Application:

1. [Implementing MVC with Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654722/implementing-mvc-with-windows-forms).
2. [How would you implement MVC in a Windows Form Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122388/how-would-you-implement-mvc-in-a-windowsforms-application)?

**Ye Olde Olde Answer**

Use [ASP.NET MVC 1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en).