# UIP Application Block in .NET 4

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, enterprise-library, .net-1.1

I am involved in migrating a legacy application built in .NET 1.1 to .NET 4.

Is UIP (User Interface Process) still available in the latest released of EnLib 5? If no, what are my options?

Regards,
Karan Misra

Comment: The exact exeception I am getting is: "Wildcard '##any' allows element 'statePersistenceProvider', and causes the content model to become ambiguous. A content model must be formed such that during validation of an element information item sequence, the particle contained directly, indirectly or implicitly therein with which to attempt to validate each item in the sequence in turn can be uniquely determined without examining the content or attributes of that item, and without any information about the items in the remainder of the sequence." I am going to investigate it now myself as well.

Comment: acronym police what UIT?

Comment: Sorry about that. Meant to write UIP.

Comment: what approach did you end up using? I am faced with a similar problem. As far as I am aware, UIP is not supported in .NET > 2.0

Comment: In case it matters to anyone anymore, I find myself maintaining a `.NET 4.7.2` application that uses the `User Interface Process (UIP) Application Block version 2`. Not sure whether or how that relates to the OP's `EnLib 5`, which I presume is `EntLib 5`. So, yes to `UIP Application Block` in `.NET 4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking (as in the Title of your question) about the User Interface Process Application Block, there have been no new official releases since 2004, as you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649689.aspx).

The options you are talking about really depend on the usage UIP was given. Take into account that there is no "easy/fast option" (and I really mean that), as other assets you will find will probably do things very different to UIP.

As the goal of UIP was mainly to provide a frame in which "navigation-like" applications could be created, you could use WWF. Other assets p&p created for decoupled applications are [SCSF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649689.aspx), [WCSF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699510.aspx) and more recently [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699510.aspx).

Comment: Is it possible to use use the latest available version of UIP in .NET 4?

Comment: I have never tried that. You would have to migrate the blocks and check for yourself. If you have the chance I would still recommend using one of the newer assets

Comment: I would also prefer doing the same. But I have to be sensitive to the client's budget.

Comment: @DamianSchenkelman I hate to say it, but the first link you posted is now dead. Which sadly has been the case for most of the UIPAB articles I come across.