# How do I call a control from within the controller using MVC?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to call a control I initialized and setup via to the view within my controller? I'm new to this design pattern and am curious how this would look? I'm using Winforms.

Comment: Winforms and controller are not friends at all! Are you using ASP.NET MVC or WinForms?

Comment: Windows Forms. I'm using the Model View Controller pattern.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this question: [How would you implement MVC in a WindowsForms application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122388/how-would-you-implement-mvc-in-a-windowsforms-application)

Comment: Oh, and this little snippet from the MSDN: [Developing with the MVC Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699294.aspx)