# Insert data into SQL table from two forms C# winform

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am trying to insert data from `frm1` and `frm2` into SQL Server at the same time. `frm1` contains product information (***barcode, qty , price, vat, total etc***) and `frm2` (***contains payments information like cash and change***). The idea is that when the user clicks the `btnfrm2` the data from `frm1` should be passed into `frm2` (***but not displayed***), and in `frm2` the user gives the payment info (***cash and change***) and after clicking `btnsave` the data from `frm1` and `frm2` should be inserted into the database.

I created a class, and a method to pass data to `frm2`.

```
    internal void mbushe(string[] args)

    {

        for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)

        {

            arka_data ad = new arka_data();

            ad.NR = int.Parse(txtnrfatures.Text);

            ad.VLERATVSHTOTAL = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);

            ad.BARKODI = int.Parse(dataTable.Rows[i][0].ToString());

            ad.EMERTIMI = dataTable.Rows[i][1].ToString();

            ad.SASIA = int.Parse(dataTable.Rows[i][2].ToString());

            ad.CMIMI = int.Parse(dataTable.Rows[i][3].ToString());

            ad.TVSH = int.Parse(dataTable.Rows[i][4].ToString());

            ad.NENTOTALI = float.Parse(txttotali.Text);

            ad.ZBRITJA = float.Parse(txtzbritja.Text);

            ad.TOTALI = float.Parse(totali.Text);

            ad.KOHA = DateTime.Now;

            ad.KASIERI = lbluser.Text;

            ad.KLIENTI = cmbklienti.Text;

            ad.VLERAETVSH = float.Parse(dataTable.Rows[i][7].ToString());

            ad.VLERAPATVSH = float.Parse(dataTable.Rows[i][6].ToString());

            ad.NRATIKUJVE = int.Parse(lblnumri.Text);

            ad.TOTALIPCS = float.Parse(dataTable.Rows[i][5].ToString());



        }

    }



    public class arka_data

    {

        public int NR { get; set; }

        public int BARKODI { get; set; }

        public string EMERTIMI { get; set; }

        public int SASIA { get; set; }

        public float CMIMI { get; set; }

        public float TVSH { get; set; }

        public float TOTAL { get; set; }

        public float NENTOTALI { get; set; }

        public float ZBRITJA { get; set; }

        public float TOTALI { get; set; }

        public DateTime KOHA { get; set; }

        public string KASIERI { get; set; }

        public string KLIENTI { get; set; }

        public float VLERAETVSH { get; set; }

        public float VLERAPATVSH { get; set; }

        public int NRATIKUJVE { get; set; }

        public float TOTALIPCS { get; set; }

        public float VLERATVSHTOTAL { get; set; }

    }
```

and in the second form I will use the elements of method( from first form)

```
         cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nrfatures", mbushe.NR);

         cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@klienti", mbushe.Barkodi)); etc
```

while mbushe is the method from first form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best if your forms use MVP pattern, AKA inherit from interface. Example

```
public class MyForm1 : Form, IView1
{
    public string SomeData { get { return MyControl1.Text } }
    . . . . 
}

public class MyForm2 : Form, IView2
{
    public string SomeOtherData { get { return MyControl1.Text } }
    . . . . 
}
```

Then you create persister, which collects the data from both forms and saves

```cs
public class FormDataPersister
{

    private IView1 _v1;
    private IView2 _v2;

    public class FormDataPersister(IView1 form1Data, IView2 form2Data)
    {
        _v1 = form1Data;
        _v2 = form2Data;        
    }

    public void Save()
    {

        // HERE collect your data into parameters and SAVE
        // EXAMPLE
         . .  . . . 
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@klienti", _v1.Barkodi));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Iview1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) @T.S how can I reference it , to be useful

Comment: @LeonardGashi `IView1` and `IView2` should be interfaces you need to declare. These interfaces should contain properties that you save in your DB. This is MVP or Model View Presenter pattern. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056/what-are-mvp-and-mvc-and-what-is-the-difference    Your form becomes view model and you can easily take the values you need as they will be mapped on the form to the control values https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vendettamit/simplest-example-of-mvp-design-patter-of-Asp-Net/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you build an object from the data on the UI and then either

1. Pass it along (from form to form) while filling it with more and more information or
2. Store it in some kind of repository so every part of the code-base has access to (preferred)

When the user then clicks the `btnsave` button on Form2, you simply call a code that persists that object.

This way you are keeping the form, its data, and the database interaction logic separate from each other.

Comment: **#2** will introduce need for state control. What if form was closed and restarted and the saved object still has old form data? **#1** will introduce need for data integrity control. What if you have not collected 1 or both forms data yet and pressed "Save"?

Comment: You can make this however complicated you like. Clicking ‘Save’ without having the data is a view-level problem. The question imo. is all about controlling state. The key take away is to decouple the data, its view and the processing logic

Comment: @NorbertHüthmayr any short example can be helpful, cause I am new to programming

Comment: @LeonardGashi A whole example would be too much but I found an interesting link that might help you understand the concept. https://stackoverflow.com/a/122565/13567181